# How to Read 'Reserved Environment Variables' from Laravel Vapor Application

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, laravel-vapor

Neither Php `$_ENV` nor `getenv()` returns the 'Vapor Reserved Environment Variables' which mentioned here: [Reserved Environment Variables](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#reserved-environment-variables)

How can we read them?

Comment: Where do you wanna read the env variable? And did you cached the config?

Comment: in the Laravel application (let's say in an HTTP controller)

Comment: If you used cache config laravel will automatically reads that from config, clear config or put your env variable in config and use after clearing the cache, see if its working.

Answer (score 0):

Read them in Laravel with `env('KEY_NAME', 'Default Value')`, just as you [regularly would](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration).